# Close to hexa ciphers

Tags: encryption

Basically this post was about a cipher with a trailing "="

Any idea is welcome :)

Comment: data:text/plain;base64,amxjb2RlYnJlYWtlcnM=

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on "=" at the end I would assume that this text might be Base64 encoded

Comment: That was it lmao !
I really thought it was like a one step process, can you explain what leads you to this ? (why is there a trailing "=" in Base64 strings ?)

Comment: @IQbrod: If you deal with security topics, you deal also with TLS, you install, send or receive TLS certificates very often, and you know the PEM format and you know, that it uses Base64. If you have seen many certificates, you know that the most of them have "=" or "==" at the end. Why? See explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6916805/why-does-a-base64-encoded-string-have-an-sign-at-the-end). Thus, it is natural to suppose that it might by Base64. Also there are no special characters, which means that Base64 is not excluded.